# password_verify always return false password

Tags: php, hash, passwords, password-hash

This is my registration code. I used password_hash with default_ password, and also use many codes for login. Probably some words would sound unfamiliar cause English is not my native language and I didn't translate unimportant words.

Here is registration code. It works, and I am able to register new user. But Login code always returns wrong password no matter what I do. I guess that problem is with registration code.

I will post login code in first response to this question because it would be too much code for one post

````
            <?php

            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "sajt");

            if($mysqli->error)
            {
                die("Error:" . $mysqli->error);
            }
            $username="";
            $email="";
            $password1="";
            $password2="";


            if(isset($_POST['insert']))
            {

                if((!$_POST['username']) || (!$_POST['email']) || (!$_POST['password1']) || (!$_POST['password2']))
                {
                    echo "Fields are empty";  
                }
                else
                {
                    $username=$_POST['username'];
                    $email=$_POST['email'];
                    $password1=$_POST['password1'];
                    $password2=$_POST['password2'];
                    $qryName = "select * from korisnik where username = '" . $_POST['username'] . "'";
                    $qryEmail = "select * from korisnik where username = '" . $_POST['email'] . "'";
                    $findEmail = $mysqli->query($qryEmail);
                    $findUsername = $mysqli->query($qryName);
                    if($findUsername->num_rows > 0)
                    {
                        echo "Username already in user!";                       
                    } 
                    else if($findEmail->num_rows > 0)
                    {
                        echo "Email already in use!";
                    }

                    $passwordHash = password_hash($password1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                    $qryInsert = "insert into korisnik (username, email, password, role)
                        VALUES ('" . $username
                        . "','" . $email 
                        . "','" . $passwordHash . "'
                        , 'User')";

                    if ($password1===$password2)
                        $result=$mysqli->query($qryInsert);                     
                    else
                        $result=false;

                    if($result)
                    {
                        ?>  
                        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <strong>Registration success!</strong>
                        </div> 
                        <?php  
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        ?> 
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <strong>Registration failed!</strong>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            }

            ?>      
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">User name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" value="<?php echo $username ?>" placeholder="Username" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>" placeholder="Email address" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password1" name="password1" value="<?php echo $password1 ?>"placeholder="Password" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password2">Repeat password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password2" name="password2" value="<?php echo $password2 ?>" placeholder="Repeat password" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="insert" value="Register" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>Register</button>
        </div>
    </form>```

Here is my last login code that always return wrong password, as every single login code I've tried before. So I post both login and register codes.

<?php
$username="";
$password="";
$conn = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root', '', 'sajt');
$error_message = "";
function error ($error) {
    echo $error;
    die();
}
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die ("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT username, password FROM korisnik";
$query = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($query)) {
        echo 'Username: ' . $row["username"] . '<br>' . 'Password: ' . $password . '<br>' . 'Hashed Password: ' . $row["password"] . '<br><br>';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $hashed_password = "SELECT password FROM korisnik WHERE username = '" . $username . "'";
        $query = mysqli_query ($conn, $hashed_password);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($query);
        $hashed_password = $row['password'];
        $password_input = password_verify($password, $hashed_password);
        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($query);
        $login_cred = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
        if ($password_input) {
            echo 'The password you entered is correct!';
        }
        else {
            echo 'The password you entered is incorrect!';
        }
    }

    ?>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form name="logovanje" method="POST">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h2>Log in</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username" value="<?php echo $username ?>" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" value="<?php echo $password ?>" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit2" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Log in<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>           
        </form>
    </div>
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem. I just didn't allocate enough space in database. I made column password, type varchar(50) instead of varchar(255).